# The /tmp directory is mistakenly deleted in Linux mint

Tags: linux

I made a  mistake and delete the /tmp directory, then I can not open website or terminal. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could go into the recovery shell on boot and then execute as root:

```
cd /
mkdir tmp
chmod a+rwxt tmp
```

This will recreate the tmp directory.

EDIT: How to get into recovery shell:

If you have some bootloader installed like GRUB for example you are presented with a list of options when booting your machine. Look for an entry with the term "recovery" in it. Choose that entry and you are again presented with a list of options. Look for "shell" or "terminal" in that list and select it. Run as root

```
 mount -o remount,rw /
```

to make sure your filesystem is mounted as read/write and execute the aforementioned commands. Usually you will automatically be logged in as root AFAIK. If not run `sudo su root` to switch roles before executing any mentioned command.

Comment: Thanks! I meet an error here. when I create the directory `tmp`, it says that "cannot create directory 'tmp' : Read-only file system". Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you run the "mount -o remount,rw /" ? This should make sure that exactly your error should not appear. In case you're not logged in as root try "sudo mount -o remount,rw /"

Comment: Thanks very much!! I have done all the commands you suggested.  Now what can i do to get off the recovery mode and then I can restart the computer?

Comment: Run "sudo reboot" ;)